# DXL get ole object name

Tags: filenames, ole, ibm-doors

i have module with text objects and ole objects inserted as icon.

I need to parse the object and if an ole object is present in that attribute, retrieve the name of the ole object.

Unfortunately, I have no idea on how to get this information.

Is there a simple way to get the OLE file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a simple way.

I just tried the following code

```
Object o = current
string s = richTextWithOle(o."Object Text")
print s
```

and looked for the filename.
The result was something like

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.18362}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa8\f0\fs20{\object\objemb{\*\objclass Word.Document.12}\objw1440\objh1215{\*\objdata 
01050000
01000000
11000000
576f72642e446f63756d656e742e313200
33000000
443a5c4d53435c446f63756d656e74735c414d495220766f6d2057617274656e20617566204672
6569686569742e646f637800
00000000
```

Part of the file name was "AMIR". Which in ASCII is 41 4D 49 52. Which is part of the 6th line of the objdata.

Perhaps it is possible to create a general rule and some code from this observation.
Good luck!

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your reply.
with your approach I can spot the file name at roughly the same location. I'll investigate in that direction.

Comment: remember that this will of course only work if the OLE file is added "from file", "as a symbol" and "linked to the file system". otherwise you will not have a file at all, only an object

Answer (score 0):

So... there is not a simple way, unfortunately.

Take a look here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014438813

The solution ends up being activating the ole in whatever program it relies on, then grabbing the name using oleGet commands. Ugh.